# asp.net how to group object in a list

Tags: c#, linq

a have a list that show the following values

```
{day:1 , product:1 , value :1} , 
{day:1 , product:2 , value :2}
{day:1 , product:3 , value :3}
.
.
.
```

i would like to have a list

```
{day:1 , details:{ {product:1 , value :1} , {product:2 , value :2},{ 
                    product:3 , value :3}
                  }
 },
{day:2 , details:{ {product:1 , value :10} , {product:2 , value :20},{ 
                    product:3 , value :30}
                  }
 },
```

can anyone help me to do it ??
thanx.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Comment: Thank you for your response Andrei but this link wasn't helpful for my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GroupBy and Anonymous type for achieving this.

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.day)
                 .Select(x=> new 
                 {
                    day=x.Key,
                    detail = x.ToList().Select(c=> 
                                      new 
                                      {
                                            product=c.product, 
                                            value=c.value
                                      })
                  });
```

Comment: thank you alot Anu you helped me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with anonymous type using linq

```
var listNew = listBase.Select(x => new
            {
                day= x.day,
                details= new
                {
                    product= x.product,
                    value = x.value
                }
            }).ToList();
```